# ExpandableListView inside ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to have a hierarchy of `ExpandableListView`, in a android project .

There will be a expandable list view , on click of the parent item it shows a child that is also a expandable list view if we click on the expandable list view lavel 2  it shows a view as a child.

Comment: do you want solution with Java and XML only ? or not ?

Answer (score 0):

as I know in android scrollable in scrollable doesn't work properly, I recommend to use hidden view inside child view inside expaldablelistview hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

We can use expandable list view as a child of parent expandable list view. Just click the link below and save the .zip file. Create a project with unzipped source files and test it.

[3 Level Expandable List](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/expandablelist3.zip)

I hope you understand it. If any doubts feel free to ask.

Answer (score -2):

you can use javascript alert to catch event.

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
    {
        ....
```